# Происхождение слова "окстись"

Tags: этимология

Есть такое слово "окстись" ("прекрати", "одумайся"). Интересно было бы узнать его происхождение, от какого оно корня.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

От слова *кстити* - крестить. Слегка усеченный в народной речи корень (крест - кст) образовал новое слово, *окстись*, со значением "перекрестись", то есть - приди в себя, скинь наваждение бесовское и тп.